# Sendgrid link tracking with google cloud dns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, sendgrid

I've been looking for a few hours to setup SendGrid link tracking when the DNS is managed at GCP DNS. But there doesn't seem to be an option similar to what Cloudflare provides where traffic can be forwarded to SendGrid.

The question is if there is anyone aware of a setup that would allow the link tracking to work Sendgrid when the dns is hosted on google cloud.

For reference, I'm currently getting a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?